# Strikethrough text in div based on conditions

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have to strikeout some text which is div based on condition. if `@MemberAddressDetails.Status` is 'Bad' I have to strikeout all of the blow `<div>` text. Can we do this with css class?

```
  <div>@MemberAddressDetails.JobTitle</div>
  <div>@MemberAddressDetails.CompanyName</div>
  <div>@MemberAddressDetails.Country</div>
  <div>@MemberAddressDetails.AddressLine1</div>
```

I can insert class name in  based on condition. that's why I am asking for div class.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for `text-decoration: line-through;`

```css
.line-through {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<div class="line-through">If you want to strike out text, use line-through.</div>
```

Comment: There is no condition though?

Comment: @KyleT that must be the back-end part. i.e. add a class.

Comment: I cannot insert `<p>` based condition.but I can insert class name in `<div>` based on condition. thats why I am asking for div class.

Answer (score 2):

Adding more to the answer by @sdcr, you can add conditional html attributes or class like given below in razor.

```
.line-through {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

   <div class="@(MemberAddressDetails.Status =="Bad" ? "line-through":"")"></div>
```